# How can I filter and loop through an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I want to be able to extract each network plan with prices from this GET API. Can someone please help me out?

I want to Extract AIRTEL DATA PLAN [dataPlan, duration,type, status, and Price for basic_user] into a select Option format.

I have done this:

```
$url = "https://subandgain.com/api/databundles.php";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$obj = json_decode($response,true);
$suppliers = array();
$customers = array();
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($obj);
foreach ($obj as $rkey => $resource){
    if ($resource['NETWORK'] == 'AIRTEL'){
        $customers[] = $resource;
    } else if ($resource['NETWORK'] == 'MTN') {
        $suppliers[] = $resource;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$dataplan = json_encode($customers);
$objs = json_decode($dataplan,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($objs);
```

Comment: Please **Edit** the question and describe what are the expected and actual results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = "https://subandgain.com/api/databundles.php";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$obj = json_decode($response, true);
$suppliers = array();
$customers = array();
$temp = array();
$dataPlan = array();
$kPrice = array();

foreach ($obj as $rkey => $resource) {

    $allPlans = array();
    foreach ($resource['BUNDLE'] as $key) {
        $dataPlan = array('dataPlan'=>$key['dataPlan'], 'duration'=>$key['duration'], 'type'=>$key['type'], 'status'=>$key['status']);
        $kPrice = array();

        foreach ($key['price'] as $keyPrice){
            $kPrice = array('price_basic_user' => $keyPrice['basic_user']);

//            $dataPlan['Price_basic_user'] = $keyPrice['basic_user']; // if you want [Price_basic_user] => 43 below [status] => Active

//            $kPrice[] = array('price_basic_user' => $keyPrice['basic_user']); // if there are multiple basic_user price uncomment
        }

        $dataPlan['Price'] = $kPrice; // comment this if you want [Price_basic_user] => 43 below [status] => Active
        $allPlans[] = $dataPlan;
    }
    $temp[$resource['NETWORK']] =  $allPlans;

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($temp);
```

Try this!

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, is the commented code necessary here?

Answer (score 0):

The $objs variable is returning json_decode. Replace with json_encode. So I made adjustments and PHP got this format.

```
<?php
$url = "https://subandgain.com/api/databundles.php";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$obj = json_decode($response,true);
$customers = array();
$suppliers = array();

foreach ($obj as $rkey => $resource){
    switch($resource['NETWORK']){
        case "AIRTEL":
            $customers[] = $resource;
            break;
        case "MTN":
            $suppliers[] = $resource;
            break;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$dataplan = json_encode($customers);
$objs = json_encode($dataplan);
echo $objs;
```

Assuming that the file where the code above is called api-plans.php, in the front file, I used the following code

```
<body>
    <div class="content"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_your_js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "api-plans.php",
            async: true,
            data: "",
            beforeSend: function() {
            },
            success: function( response ) {
                responseJson = JSON.parse(response);
                var contentHTML = "";
                var responseJsonNetWork = responseJson[0]['BUNDLE'];

                $.each(responseJsonNetWork, function(i, item) {
                    contentHTML = contentHTML + "Data Plan: " + responseJsonNetWork[i]['dataPlan'] + "<br />";
                    contentHTML = contentHTML + "Duration: " + responseJsonNetWork[i]['duration'] + "<br />";
                    contentHTML = contentHTML + "Type: " + responseJsonNetWork[i]['type'] + "<br />";
                    contentHTML = contentHTML + "Status: " + responseJsonNetWork[i]['status'] + "<br />";
                    contentHTML = contentHTML + "Price (basic_user): " + responseJsonNetWork[i]['price'][0]['basic_user'] + "<br /><br />";
                });

                $(".content").html(contentHTML);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. 1. Changing `if` to `switch` is unnecessary if the the rest of the code is the same. 2. The OP didn't ask anything about AJAX, why provide it?

Comment: Thanks for the reception. Well, I read some articles on the subject and the conclusion is the following, most of the time the switch will be faster than if else because it indexes the possible results as constants, but that will depend on the language and the optimization that it uses he has. About the ajax solution, the question tags are measuring the json, so I decided to put together a complete example for him to test.

Comment: `switch` maybe be faster, but how does it answer to the question?

Comment: Just a scalability vision for the project.